# Getting a row's position inside a MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have a table where I store the standings data of a racing championship. The problem is - I don't actually store the driver's position, but I just store the number of points along with other data (number of wins, etc.) and then let MySQL sort it for me. This usually works fine, but what if I want to know a driver's position in a certain season? I could go with the following code:

```
SELECT  l.driver, @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS position
FROM    driverStandings l
JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
WHERE   l.season = 1
ORDER BY l.points DESC, l.racesWon DESC
```

However, this would return a list of every driver and his/her position in season 1. If I just wanted to know a driver's (e.g. "Vettel") position, what could I do? I've tried everything I could think of, to no avail.

Comment: Honestly I think for efficiency reasons (especially down the line) you should just pre-calculate the position and store it in a field of driverstandings. This will not only make the driver query simple it will also make this query more straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT       COUNT(v.id) + 1
FROM         driverStandings d
  LEFT JOIN  driverStandings v
         ON  d.points > v.points
         OR (d.points = v.points AND d.racesWon > v.racesWon)
WHERE        v.id = ?
```

If you want, you can `GROUP BY` instead of filtering on `v.id` (just remember to add it to the `SELECT` list in order that you can identify each record though).

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I was looking for - I really need to look into JOIN, because that's something I haven't ever used. Again, many thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

Do a select count where points are greater than that driver's points. This would be easiest in a second query, but there is that chance of a race condition (no pun intended).

select (count(*) + 1) as position from driverStandings l where l.points > :driverPoints

Comment: Thanks, but there is a slight problem with that - if two or more drivers have the same amount of points, we don't have any tiebreaker, and I really need to look at the amount of races each driver has won.

Comment: In that case I'd go with the pre-compute suggestion above and use insert/update triggers to update everyone's position when a driver's points or win/loss is updated.

Answer (score 0):

you really ought to store the position explicitly as mentioned in the comment to your original post. it will make all of the code surrounding this problem cleaner.

it should be possible to fill the values so the new driver position field is filled with the current row as in your example using an [inert...select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html)

however you could also make a get the same info inefficiently using a sub query

Comment: Thanks, that's a very good point. The problem is, I don't really want to get a driver's position on the table very often - most of the time, I just want to get the entire table. Adding a "position" column would make it easier for me to calculate this, but it would mean storing redundant information, so I could end up with incoherent data!